# Finding the intersection of 2 functions

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions, graphing-functions

I keep making mistakes with these kinds of questions when the algebra is a little harder.

$g(x)=x^2-4x+6$

$h(x)=3\sqrt x$

I see the answer is $1$ and $4$? How to reach this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Do you mean $h(x)=3\sqrt x$ ?

Comment: In general, you solve the equation $g(x) = h(x)$ or $g(x) - h(x) =0$, which in this case comes to $x^2 -4x + 6 - 3\sqrt{x} = 0$. Since this is not a normal quadratic equation, one has to use some numerical methods (or cleverness, if the solution is somehow easily visible).

Comment: Graphing the functions can acts as a numerical method. So just plot the two functions in the same graph and find the intersection points.

Comment: Ah yes sorry, I did mean that. And OK, so I will try sketching the graph. Thanks for your input. I started multiplying the power by its reciprocal and then began to get some weird numbers...

Answer (score 2):

With $x=t^2$, the equation becomes

$$t^4-4t^2-3t+6=0.$$

[Anyway, as $\sqrt x$ is a non-negative number, we must restrict to $t\ge0$.]

There are closed-form formulas to solve such quartic polynomials in the general cas, but they are tedious.

If you assume that the problem has been arranged so that the roots are integer, then it suffices to try the divisors of $6$, namely $\pm1,\pm2,\pm3$ and $\pm6$.

It turns out that $t=1$ and $t=2$ are solutions, so that the equation factors as

$$t^4-4t^2-3t+6=(t^2+at+b)(t-1)(t-2).$$

By long division, the quadratic factor is $t^2+3t+3$, which doesn't have real roots.